# Is it possible to create a C++ class which can be initialized by a given constant number?

Tags: c++

Here `two_t` and `three_t` are 2 hypothetical classes which bind to the constants 2 and 3 respectively.

```
int foo(two_t)
{
    return 10;
}

int foo(three_t)
{
    return 20;
}

int bar()
{
    return foo(3); // 20 is returned
}
```

Edit: Motivation for this question:

I was thinking about this because it's possible to make an overload of the function `foo` which accepts 0. You can do that by using the type `std::nullptr_t`. That's why I was wondering if you could do that with other numerical constants too.

Comment: No, you have to make them different types. Why do you need this? What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Would you be okay with `foo<3>()` instead of `foo(3)`?

Comment: @NathanOliver - I know you can do `foo<3>()` using templates. I'm curious if you can do the latter case.

Comment: @ShivanshuGoyal AFAIK you cannot do it like you have in the question.

Comment: @Brian - I added the motivation in the question

Comment: The 0 thing is a special case, which only exists in the language because C didn't have `nullptr`.

Comment: Your reasoning is flawed; the case of `std::nullptr_t` is not at all comparable. If you had `foo(int)` and `foo(std::nullptr_t)`, `foo(0)` would resolve to `foo(int)`.  It would only call `foo(std::nullptr_t)` with an explicit cast.

Comment: @Clifford: No explicit cast needed; an implicit conversion is quite sufficient.  For example: `char* p; foo(p = 0);`

Comment: If it will be a integer constant, why not use a template and specialize for a given value? So you would call it like `foo<3>();`. I don't see much use for it but its possible.

Comment: @BenVoigt  : OK, though still does not justify the OP's flawed reasoning.  There is no magic or exception regarding nullptr/0; it is entirely consistent.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use

```
return foo(3);
```

and expect `3` to be converted to `three_t` and not `two_t` based solely on the value of the argument.

An argument cannot be uniquely converted to a type based solely on it is value.

The standard explicitly makes the exception for a constant expression of integer type that evaluates to zero and `std::nullptr_t`. That is correct. There are no other exceptions that I can think of.

Comment: But 0 can bind to `std::nullptr_t`, so you can make a function which only accepts 0, and no other number.

Comment: @ShivanshuGoyal, it can also bind to an `int`, `float`, `char,` `double`, and whole host of types.

Comment: Sure, 0 binds to a whole host of types. But my argument is, you have a type which _only_ binds to a single numerical constant. And being able to specify what that numerical constant is for a custom type sounds kind of interesting.

Comment: @ShivanshuGoyal that sounds like a feature, but it's actually an obsolete compatibility quirk from before we had `nullptr`. It only works with `0`.

Comment: The `std::nullptr_t` is not an exception at all.  You can implicitly cast an integer zero to a null pointer, but if there is an overload for `int` that will be called - the use of zero would not "select" the null pointer overload without an explicit cast.

Answer (score -3):

> Is it possible to create a C++ class which can be initialized by a given constant number?

Yes, but you won't like it...

... 
...

Are you sure you want to do this? Hmm. Fine, here you go:

```
class A { A (int) { } };
```

See? I said you wouldn't like it. Honestly, though, you're trying to address a different problem and you're asking for what is probably the wrong solution. This is called an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here on the site.